# What does <param name="location"> mean in struts.xml?

Tags: struts2

Originally, I'm trying to figure out what

```xml
<param name="location">
```

means in a `struts.xml` file, see below:

```xml
<action name="hello" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" method="execute">
<result name="success" type="redirect">
<param name="location">
/NewWorld.jsp
</param >
</result>
</action>
```

source:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_result_types.htm

the tutorial does say:

"We can provide the location either in the body of the `<result...>` element or as a `<param name="location">` element. Redirect also supports the parse parameter. Here's an example
configured using XML:"

So does location equal the url or something else?

I googled, and in both of these sites, below, though I'm able to understand `<param name="fruit">`, but I don't understand how it gets turned into

```xml
<s:param name="fruit">
```

, note the s.  I do know that the stands for Struts and is a struts element, but what does that have to do with

```xml
<param name=”fruit">
```

?  One is in a xml file and the other is in a JSP.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/param.html
“Struts 2 “param” tag is used to parametrize other tags.”  I also don’t understand what this means and what it has to do with my original question.

original source of confusion in red, more specifically, what does `<param name=”location”>` mean?

Comment: I don't understand any of the answers below.  what does <param name="location"> mean, and can it be <param name="anythingIwant">  What exactly does it do?  Can someone please write in simple english since this is a total newbie?

Comment: Also, how come I didn't receive an email notification when people reply?

Comment: result contains the name the jsp page which will be executed or shown to user according to your class code. suppose your class method returned success and your action tag contains <result name=success>/success.jsp</result> . It will show sucess.jsp when your class method returns sucess string. See on of the example I have posted. check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61402861/11498860

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code is used to redirect to a new page, location parameter will be passed to define the page that need to be shown. (Request should be redirected to)

Answer (score 0):

the "shorthand" version in example, where we provided a JSP path as the body of the result tag.

```
<result name="success" type="dispatcher">   //type="dispatcher" by default so also can ignore this thing
/WEB-INF/login.jsp
</result>
```

We can also specify the JSP file using a  tag within the  element, in case we don't feel we've typed enough.

```
<result name="success" type="dispatcher">
<param name="location">
/WEB-INF/login.jsp
</param>
</result>
```

We can also supply a parse parameter, which is true by default. The parse parameter determines whether or not the location parameter will be parsed for OGNL expressions.

Answer (score 0):

In the result configuration the `param` tag specifies a property of the `Result` which would be set when result executes. This property might present in the `ServletRedirectResult`. This class is determined by the result type configuration in `struts-default.xml`. More about redirect result you can find [here](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/redirect-result.html). The `location` is the *default* property, so it could be set in the body of the `result` tag without specifying `param`. The `param` tag can be used in the `struts.xml` to set properties of the configuration objects. The `s:param` tag is different, because it's a JSP tag. It *can be* used to parametrize other JSP tags, that can populate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The `<param name="location">` in the `struts.xml` points to a resource that should be returned.

In your example it points to the resource located at `/NewWorld.jsp`, so `/NewWorld.jsp` will be rendered and returned (as the response), if your action-method returned the String `success`.

It has to be named `location`, otherwise it would not work.
If you take a look into the class `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport` you will find a property named `location`. This property will be populated with the value from the `<param name="location">`.

You will also find a property named `encode`. If you want to change the `encode`-property you would use a `<param name="encode">`.

Do not mix up the `param`-tag in the `struts.xml` with a `s.param`-Tag used in a jsp-file (or in any other resource-file). They are not related at all.

I hope this answer helps you to understand the other answers, for they are more accurate than mine.