# cannot run Struts 2 Hello World

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action-mapping

Problem
When I run my project and try to run

```
    ERROR Dispatcher Dispatcher initialization failed
     Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.5/wtpwebapps/Struts2Test/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.5.22.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:162
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
 and more...
```

http://localhost:8081/Struts2Test/testAction

[image: Project Structure]

It does not work. It show HTTP status 404(On my browser)

**Eclipse Console**

There are no errors on Eclipse Console

/Struts2Test/src/struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="test" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="testAction" class="test.Action.TestAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">
                /success.jsp
            </result>
            <result name="error">
                /error.jsp
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

TestAction.java

```
package test.Action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TestAction extends ActionSupport
{
    public String execute()
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

/Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Struts2Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you actually *using* the GXP plugin?

Comment: I do not know. How can I check that Am I using GXP plugin or not?@Dave Newton

Comment: ... If you don't know then you're not using it. Do not randomly put S2 libraries in your app; use only what you need. I'd recommend using Maven.

Comment: I placed my struts.xml file  inside the package by mistake. It is not visible in the project structure. Last night I went through lot of stackoverflow post with similar issues. I realized that struts.xml for maven projects should be inside classes WEB-INF/classes and for dynamic web projects it should be inside src folder. Although I still do not understand why It should be on the classpath?@Dave Newton

Comment: Because it's loaded from the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello World(in struts)

Create a dynamic web project in Eclipse Enterprise edition

Eclipse>File>New>Dynamic Web Project

Name it: HelloWorld

It should have web.xml file in Web content folder>WEB-INF>web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Create a Class TestAction.java

(/HelloWorld/src/com/test/TestAction.java)

```
package com.test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TestAction extends ActionSupport
{
    public String execute()
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

/HelloWorld/WebContent/success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

/HelloWorld/src/struts.xml

**Note:** Your struts.xml file should be inside src folder of your dynamic web project. Otherwise it will not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="test" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="testAction" class="com.test.TestAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">
                /success.jsp
            </result>
            <result name="error">
                /error.jsp
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

[Download essential jar files from struts site](http://apachemirror.wuchna.com/struts/2.5.22/struts-2.5.22-min-lib.zip)

You need to add these jar files in your Java Build Path

Select your Project>Right Click>Properties>Java Build Path>Add External Jar files

Now, You need to add these jar files in Deployment Assembly

Select your Project>Right Click>Properties>Deployment Assembly>Add>Click on Java Build Path>The jar files which you added earlier will be present there. Select and ok.

Run your project on Server

Select your project> Run as>Run on Server

On your browser

http://localhost:8081/HelloWorld/testAction

(I changed my port number from 8080 to 8081. Default port number for Tomcat is 8080. So the URL will http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/testAction. )